# Animations appear, rotate and disappear

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, rotation

I want to do a multiple animations on my image (appear -> rotate -> disappear). I've got this code:

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<alpha
    android:duration="1"
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:toAlpha="100" />

</set>
```

fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<alpha
    android:duration="1"
    android:fromAlpha="100"
    android:toAlpha="0" />

</set>
```

image_rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<rotate
    android:duration="2500"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="120" />

</set>
```

Also in my java code:

```
animRotate= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.image_rotate);
animRotate.setDuration((long) duration);
fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_out);

AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);
s.addAnimation(fade_in);
s.addAnimation(animRotate);
s.addAnimation(fade_out);

image.startAnimation(s);
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work correctly...

Comment: doesn't work correcrly?

Comment: Also you have set the animation duration to 1 = 1milliSecond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have severals errors in your animation xml files:

- the duration property is in milliseconds, so 1ms is way too short for a noticeable fade in/fade out animation
- the alpha property is a float between 0 et 1, 100 is way too much.
- you don't need a set in your xml files if there is only one animation : just add the alpha or rotate tag as a root

So, you should have now these files:

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:toAlpha="1" />
```

fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0" />
```

image_rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2500"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="120" />
```

Then, in your code, you need a add an offset between each animation. Otherwise, all the animations will be triggered at the same time. Moreover, the **fillAfter** flag must be set on the root animation object (here, your `AnimationSet`)

```
Animation animRotate= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.image_rotate);
Animation fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_in);
Animation fade_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fade_out);

AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);
s.addAnimation(fade_in);

animRotate.setDuration((long) duration);
animRotate.setStartOffset(fade_in.getDuration());
s.addAnimation(animRotate);

fade_out.setStartOffset(fade_in.getDuration() + animRotate.getDuration());
s.addAnimation(fade_out);

s.setFillAfter(true);

image.startAnimation(s);
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Sorry about that.
Better use this library:- https://github.com/sam43/AnimateViewLibrary